# How to reverse course when there is no published course reversal?

Tags: approach, instrument-procedures

[image]Coming from the SW on the RNAV RWY 15 KONO, how do I align myself with the final approach course?  There is only one IAF and no published course reversal.  Is it up to me how I get established inbound?
[RNAV 15]

Answer (score 6):

If the approach doesn't contain a published course reversal (ie PT barb or Hold-In-Lieu), the approach must be flown straight in. In this case, you will either get vectors-to-final or you will get cleared via one of the feeder routes.

Comment: Specifically, ATC will not (cannot?) clear you for a straight-in approach that requires a turn >90° at the IAF; this is why so many RNAV IAPs have a "Basic T". This one doesn't, but PIYID and NEYGI serve the same general purpose, and being on V269 makes them easy to file to.

Comment: Right...that was the logic behind me discounting ATC clearing the aircraft Direct CEYTA.

Answer (score 1):

It's a RNAV approach. You just fly to PIYID waypoint and that's all. I think all those reversals very useful when there was no RNAV and there was no other reliable way to establish on the final approach course unless you had VOR's and NDB's not at the airport to assist with that. Now it does not make sense. Why to fly more miles if you can fly this approach as published directly.

There are 3 real life situations:

1. If you fly commercially you will have a flight plan that will end at PIYID.
2. If you just fly somewhere and ask tower for the approach you will get direct to PIYID.
3. If it is uncontrolled airport probably it will make sense to go directly to PIYID... or other waypoint.

Comment: "Why fly more miles"...  Your recommendation to PIYID then CEYTA essentially creates a 9.9 nm base leg.  I would prefer to reduce that.

Answer (score 0):

"Approach, (callsign) request 3 mile offset to the west at CEYTA for alignment."

The offset you request will be what is necessary to execute a roughly 180 deg turn to the inbound course.  Keep it snug, but don't cheat yourself out of the space needed to make a comfortable turn in IMC with a little bit of wings level time before you hit the fix.

ATC knows you can't get there and pivot in place, and are usually very accommodating if it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: Assuming you fly in the US, ATC will not give you this clearance! They will either give you vectors-to-final, or they will give you direct PIYID for the feeder. They aren't allowed to give turns of more than 30 degrees to intercept the final approach course, nor are you allowed as the pilot to perform your own unpublished course reversal.

Comment: Not true unless this is a recent change.  I haven't flown IFR in 13 years, but I flew continuously for the 16 years prior to that and I have asked for and received this many times.

Comment: ... in the United States.